# How does code from different languages get integrated in the same platform?

Tags: c, linux, rust, compiler-construction, jit

First and foremost, I'm no expert in software, and I realize this question might be as vague as it gets (it's just a curiosity), and get ready to read some barbaric guesses from my part!

The question came up from reading an article on how Linux's developers were implementing Rust into their OS (https://www.zdnet.com/article/linus-torvalds-on-where-rust-will-fit-into-linux/).

What does it even mean to implement Rust in their OS? Do they have some compiled code written in C that calls compiled code that resulted from writing in Rust? I don't see how this can efficiently be done, as you'd have different compilers probably being unable to optimize code, since, along the way, it's calling "foreign" code. I imagine the situation gets worse if you throw a language like Python or Java into the mix, which aren't precompiled. Now you would have JVM or PVM running together with compiled code, which, I imagine, would be highly impractical. One approach I can conceive, is if you see all these things as separate processes, and you'd simply have code from one language starting a process that corresponds to code from another language, but again, I imagine that wouldn't be very efficient...

Again, I realize I could've been more direct, but I'm not looking for a specific answer which addresses a problem, but rather general insight on how different languages can get used together. Thanks for understanding!

Comment: Like, literally https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface . But overall, I do not understand the question. Why different languages can't call each other? Why not?`I don't see how this can efficiently be done` Do you ask _how_ or ask about efficiency. Still, in C usually each file is optimized separately, so there's no difference, and LTO is too costly to run anyway.

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm not saying they can't, I'm saying I don't see how they can. For instance, if the C compiler has a specific way of managing the stack, that is completely different from how Rust manages stack, there's a chance that calling Rust code will mess up with the stack as it was from the C code because it makes certain assumptions that don't hold true anymore. Because they share the same process, memory isn't protected. In the other case of using VM's (Python/Java) every time a little bit of code needs to run, we need to recheck code version, see if it needs updating, and run it in the VM.

Comment: `if the C compiler has a specific way of managing the stack, that is completely different from how Rust manages stack` But it's not, it's the same. The rules of that are governed by _ABI_ ie. https://uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf . Still, in case a language does use stack differently, then "just" handle that case specially. I do not understand anything about that Python/Java stuff - Python is written in C, so anything you write in Python, is executed by C, and C calls other C functions (to simplify a lot). The same with JVM. And it's not a "virtual machine", it's more of an interpreter.

Comment: On the other side, I believe that except for researching what is "ABI", you should also research what is a "linker" and "linking", how linking and shared libraries work and what does `dlopen()` do. And ELF file format. I think these topics might give you better understanding.

Comment: I see, just learned about ABI. I saw that mentioned in the article, but didn't pay much mind to it. I guess that makes sense. And @user253751 gave me a pretty good idea on how to integrate VM-based languages as well. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically when compiling a source file we have a set of options for outputs generated by the compiler, like creating a binary application from the `main` function, a statically linkable binary or a dynamically linkable library, or in other cases, source to source transformations.

The kernel is written in C, and to be able to compile large codebases like the kernel, we often decide to compile each, or a set of source files (the proper term would be translation unit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) into a statically linked library or object files. Once we've gathered all of the object files and statically (or shared) linked libraries we can link these together and produce a final binary/library.

When we're talking about integrating Rust code into the kernel, we're talking about using statically linked libraries from C in Rust and vice versa. The process of calling code produced from other compilers or languages is named Foreign Function Interface, or FFI.

There are many details and challenges with FFI including ABIs or name mangling to name a few. ABI, or application binary interface is one of the issues mentioned in your article. Unlike C, Rust does not have a stable ABI yet, meaning there's no guarantee the symbols in the static library compiled from Rust won't have different names or data layouts in the future. This means that code compiled using Rust's compiler may not be compatible with previous Rust compiler outputs which would require the C code to be updated every time there's an ABI change.

Comment: I see, seems like it's a matter of time until we can integrate them seamlessly, then. I'll be doing some reading on FFI, feel like I opened up a whole new world, but then again that happens every time I ask about a topic I'm not totally comfortable with! Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how a C program is traditionally compiled:

- Each source file is compiled - separately! - into an object file, which contains machine code, and placeholders for connecting all the object files together.
- All the object files are joined together and the placeholders are filled in.

If you can generate some of those object files using Rust instead of C, the C compiler can't tell the difference. It's no different from a different C file!

---

You need to make sure the functions that cross the language barrier need to be valid functions for both languages. For example, you might not be able to pass structures as arguments, or return structures, if that's not valid in Rust (I don't actually know) - you might only be able to use primitive values, like ints and floats and pointers. If the Rust machine code expects float variables to be in certain registers, but the C machine code puts them in different registers, you might not be able to pass floats. Or you might have to put a special hint to one or the other compiler, to say "the argument goes in *this* register, dummy!"  If the Rust compiler people didn't cooperate with the C compiler people, you are likely to run into a few of these kinds of problems, but with a bit of luck, they can all be worked around.

Since the function needs to be valid in both languages, you also need to write a C header file. You can't #include a Rust file - well you can, but it won't work - so you need to write the function declarations *again* in C syntax so the C compiler can understand what they are.

---

For languages which require VMs, it's complicated in a different way.

Usually these languages are so different from C that you can't just link together the machine code. Instead you have to use the VM's API to initialize the VM, load the code, and call the code. Something like this:

```
    // not real code, just an illustration of how it could work

    // How C starts a JVM and calls a Java method (a Java function)
    void run_jvm() {
        jvm_t *jvm = create_jvm();
        jvm_class_t *main_class = jvm_load_class(jvm, "Main.class");
        jvm_method_t *main_method = jvm_get_method(jvm, main_class, "main", NULL);
        jvm_call(jvm, main_method, NULL, NULL);
        delete_jvm(jvm);
    }

    // how Java calls a C function
    void Java_HelloPrinter_printHello(jvm_t *jvm, jvm_object_t *this, jvm_args_t *args) {
        printf("Hello world! My argument is %d\n", jvm_args_get_int(args, 1));
    }

    // how the method is declared in Java
    public class HelloPrinter {
        public static native void printHello(int i);
        //            ^^^^^^
        // this means it's a C function
    }
```

In Python or Lua, being more dynamic languages, the interpreter doesn't look for things for you. Instead, you put your functions into variables before you run any of your Python code.

```
    // not real code, just an illustration of how it could work

    // How Python calls a C function
    void printHelloFunction(pvm_t *pvm, pvm_args_t *args) {
        printf("Hello world! My argument is %d\n", pvm_args_get_int(args, 1));
    }

    // How C starts a PVM and calls a Python method
    void run_python() {
        pvm_t *pvm = create_pvm();
        pvm_variable_t *var = pvm_create_global_variable(pvm, "printHello");
        pvm_set_variable_as_c_function(pvm, var, &printHelloFunction);
        pvm_load_module_from_file(pvm, "main.py");
        delete_pvm(pvm);
    }
```

These languages are not on equal footing with C, but Rust is, because Rust compiles to machine code. If you could run Java or Python code outside of a VM, they could be on equal footing. There used to be a compiler called `gcj` which would compile Java into machine code, but it's no longer maintained. Someone could write one, although it wouldn't run most Java programs, because a lot of those programs need to do stuff with the VM (like reflection).

Comment: I know how compilers work (well, the C compiler at least). But it was the using code from multiple compilers together that was confusing me, since it would be expected they manage things differently with different assumptions. I just learned of ABI, and it does make sense for languages to have this, but I wasn't aware of it. Also thanks for clearing up how VM languages can be integrated as well, that was a fairly intuitive explanation!